# Working with filtered data frame

Tags: r

I have a lot of columns and row with diffrent countries/cities etc. My data:

```
Country | City   | Language | Age |Q1  |Q2 |Q3 |Q4
--------|--------|----------|-----|----|---|---|--   
    USA | Boston |English   |21   |12  |12 |14 |6
  Spain | Madrit |Spanish   |21   |10  |9  |13 |15
```

I would like to run verious tets/statistics between diffrent groups. And here's come my problem: what is the best code technicue to do that?

User choose conditions ( let's say country level). Now I should have receive following results ( all country combinations):

```
Countries |Q1 p value| Q2 p value| etc
USA SPAIN | 0.01     | 0.10
USA Brazil| 0.05     | 0.15
```

User may choose Language and city level ( all combinations languages+city):

```
Language+City                     |Q1 p value| Q2 p value| etc
Boston English; Madrit English    | 0.01     | 0.10
Boston English; Madrit Spanisch   | 0.05     | 0.15
```

Basically I do not know what is the best way to do that? I thought about a lot of 'for' loops + 'if conditions'. But then I read about extracting subsets and then working on them. Or do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance for any hint :)

Comment: Are these p values from two-proportion t tests?

Comment: What do you mean with "User choose conditions"? Is this a Shiny App? A package? A (group of) function to facilitate the tests?

Comment: bramtayl Yes, p - values from some nonparametric tests
@Molx I thought about sth like 'Check_country= TRUE , Check_city=TRUE, Check_age= FALSE' at the beginning of the code. I would like to have it as much flexible as possible. I will creat some VBA macro in excel and it will connect with R to run the statistics. In the excel spreedsheet user will choose a) 'granuality ' (country or country and city or city and age etc) b) questions ( q1 or Q1 and Q3 or all questions)